# What are the access-specifiers available in c#? What is the default one?

Tags: c#

What are the access-specifiers available in c#? What is the default one?

Comment: @Preet Sangha, and now if someone does google it, there's a good chance that this question will come up as an answer! =)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The possible access modifiers are :

- private
- protected
- internal
- protected internal
- public

The default modifier that is used, depends on the element.

- For classes, the default specifier is
  'internal'
- For class-members, the default
  specifier is private
- For nested types (inner classes), the
  default is private

You can also find it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(VS.71).aspx)

You might find it also interesting to have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Note that for *nested* types the default is "private"

Answer (score 2):

A copy of the C# Language Specification is included when you install Visual Studio (in 2008 at least), at `VSRoot\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.doc`. This is, of course, the definitive place to look.

Answer (score 1):

Access Modifiers (Access Specifiers) describes as the scope of accessibility of an Object and its members. All C# types and type members have an accessibility level . We can control the scope of the member object of a class using access specifiers. We are using access modifiers for providing security of our applications. When we specify the accessibility of a type or member we have to declare it by using any of the access modifiers provided by CSharp language.

C# provide **five** access specifiers , they are as follows :

**public, private , protected , internal and protected internal** .

**public :**

public is the most common access specifier in C# . It can be access from anywhere, that means there is no restriction on accessibility. The scope of the accessibility is inside class as well as outside. The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.

**private :**

The scope of the accessibility is limited only inside the classes or struct in which they are declared. The private members cannot be accessed outside the class and it is the least permissive access level.

**protected :**

The scope of accessibility is limited within the class or struct and the class derived (Inherited )from this class.

**internal :**

The internal access modifiers can access within the program that contain its declarations and also access within the same assembly level but not from another assembly.

**protected internal :**

Protected internal is the same access levels of both protected and internal. It can access anywhere in the same assembly and in the same class also the classes inherited from the same class .